# Time complexity of a simple while loop

Tags: java, swift, while-loop, time-complexity

I am confused as to the time complexity of this code.

```
int a = 1;

while ( a < n ) {
  a = a * 2;
}
```

I am new to time complexities

Comment: Well, what are you confused about?

Comment: Just wanted to be sure it is `o(n)`

Comment: I think it's log n.

Comment: well, I don't think the question is a duplicate of the linked one

Comment: @abc Neither do I.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's log(n). If `n` is 4, the loop executes 2 times.
If `n` is 8, the loop executes 3 times.
If `n` is 16, the loop executes 4 times.

That's a logarithmic relationship, not a linear one.

Answer (score 2):

If you check for the values `a` can get you will see:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...,
```

and the iterations will continue until `a` is smaller than `n`,
which means that the number of iterations is bounded by `⌈log2(n)⌉`.

You can thus conclude that the time complexity is logarithmic in `n`.